# Why I get different from my system language in debian console?

Tags: kde, debian, locale

Please help me to understand how debian(kde) decides what language to use in terminal (konsole).
My system language is English, but all input requests, info messages in konsole (e.g.: password) I get on Russian. Why?
My locale:

```
LANG=en_IL
LANGUAGE=en_US:ru:he
LC_CTYPE="en_IL"
LC_NUMERIC="en_IL"
LC_TIME="en_IL"
LC_COLLATE="en_IL"
LC_MONETARY="en_IL"
LC_MESSAGES="en_IL"
LC_PAPER="en_IL"
LC_NAME="en_IL"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IL"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IL"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IL"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IL"
LC_ALL=
```

I additional info is needed, please ask

Comment: Debian is [not supported here](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). Ask at https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: ok, and I got the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have other languages after `en_US` in the `LANGUAGE` list. Replace

```
LANGUAGE=en_US:ru:he
```

with

```
LANGUAGE=en_US
```